# Undo update in mysql, data still in .myd file

Tags: mysql, undo

I did the classical stupid mistake and I updated rows in MySQL table without WHERE condition (via PHP script), so all rows are affected. I don't have any recent backup.

I can still see the data before the update in .myd file.

I thought of copying and pasting the data back, but the problem is, the data wasn't in english, and if I open the .myd in notepad, non-english characters look "damaged" (they were fine in mysql, I was using utf8_unicode_ci).

So, is there any chance to get the data back in correct encoding? Or can I somehow edit out the update from the .myd file?

Comment: no, you're pretty much hosed. restore from backup, or rebuild the db. deleting in a db is just like deleting on a harddrive. an index/catalog entry is marked as "available", but the data remains until overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

seems duplicated with [How to rollback the effect of last executed mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839269/how-to-rollback-the-effect-of-last-executed-mysql-query)

don't edit mysql binary file, copy them if you want it to help making queries to updates columns to desired state.